# WI-FI connection Windows 11

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11

I use Windows 11 Home on my laptop and I faced with a weird problem. After I reboot the laptop it can not connect to any WiFi network except my smartphone's one. I have to activate WiFi hotspot on my phone and connect my laptop to this hotspot. After that I can switch to any WiFi connection. So I can not use Internet with my laptop without the smartphone. My phone is Xiaomi MI 8. Ho do I solve this problem?

Comment: Not normal. Run DISM / SFC and see if that fixes the issue.  ...........    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: ***"...can not connect..."*** isn't very descriptive of the issue. What exactly happens when you try to connect (and to what network/s do you try)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool such as Nirsoft's [WiFiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html), below, to view the connection when it is working.

[image: WiFiInfoiView]

Right-click on the connection and *Create Desktop Shortcut,* preferably by BSSID.

Nest time there's an issue after reboot (or awaking from Sleep or Hibernation), double-click the shortcut to the connection and it should start in a second or two. As to *why* Windows loses connectivity, that seems to be an ongoing, though intermittent, issue since Windows 10.